# Transaction id in email notification gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity

I need help  to Insert Transaction id in notification email sent to admin in gravity form,

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i want to insert transaction which is shown in entries section of gravity form in insert merge tag drop down.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add this to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'gform_replace_merge_tags', 'replace_transaction_id', 10, 7 );
function replace_transaction_id( $text, $form, $entry, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format ) {
    $transaction_id = empty( $transaction_id ) ? rgar( $entry, 'transaction_id' ) : $transaction_id;
    $text = str_replace( '{transaction_id}', $transaction_id, $text );
    return $text;
}
```

Then, you can add the following merge tag into your Gravity Forms notification area:

```
{transaction_id}
```

Hope this helps, even though it's been a very long time since your question, I was searching for this answer on Google and came to this page, and then ended up tracking down the answer so I am sharing it here.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to pull in a transaction id from Payeezy with Gravity Forms.